# motd displayed twice

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, motd

So here's the deal. I've created `/etc/motd.tail` as suggested by Ubuntu documentation which should append STATIC content to `/etc/motd` . However as well as this work, it displays the MOTD TWICE when I log on to the server via ssh. 
W00t ?! Is there any way to fix this ? This does seem like a bug to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

For me it was two places causing motd to be displayed twice:

1. pam.d
2. sshd

#### 1

`~> cd /etc/pam.d
~> grep -i motd *`
and then editing `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to hash out these two lines:

`session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate`

(May differ from version to version so confirm with grep output.)

#### 2

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` also had `#PrintMotd=yes` (default is yes so it was active even if it was #'d out)

---

In the end I set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` MOTD option to `PrintMotd=no` (not removed the # and set to no to replace the default) and enabled the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` motd lines so the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` option `printlastlog=yes` will print the last login information *after* the pam.d motd is displayed.

Pam will also use the options in `/etc/update-motd.d/` to customise the /etc/motd as well which sshd will not do as it will simply display what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Bug, no...

It sounds like you have something wrong in your `~/.bashrc` file. Look and see if there are any lines which add `motd.tail`. Maybe look for `motd*`?

If that doesn't work, just append directly to MOTD. Command:

```
sudo -i
cat /etc/motd.tail >> /etc/motd
```

Then, you can (if you want), `rm /etc/motd.tail`.
Get out of root by `exit`ing.

Just remember to directly edit the `motd` file as a workaround.

Comment: Its a fresh install. So, if there is something weird with the bashrc files it certainly hasn't been updated by us :(
Updating motd directly defies the point of motd.tail - isn't that going to be overridden. My understanding is that motd is DYNAMICALLY created whilst motd.file should contain just static content.